# Using multiple models in one view Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to follow a few tutorials on how to do this but I am coming out with no results.

I have to use two models in my view and they're both retrieving data from the database but when I try to combine them into one view it says I'm getting a null result. How can I query from the database and return both models to the view?

## User.cs

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
}
```

## Course.cs

```
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string CourseDescription { get; set; }
}
```

## CommonViewModel

```
public class CommonViewModel
{
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
    public List<Course> courses { get; set; }
}
```

## DefaultConnection.cs

```
    public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
    {
        public DefaultConnection() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Vehicles { get; set; }
    }
```

## View

```
@model TEST.Models.CommonViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.users)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
}
```

## HomeController

```
private DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection();

       public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<User> users = new List<User>();

            List<Course> courses = new List<Course>();

            var viewModel = new CommonViewModel();
            viewModel.users = users;
            viewModel.courses = courses;

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Like the error says: Your CommonViewModel doesn't, in fact, have a definition for "users". It DOES have a definition for "user".

Comment: Ah I got it now, but now I get an error saying it is null, do I have to add CommonViewModel to my dbcontext or something?

Comment: `CommonViewModel`'s properties should be public & `List`

Comment: I actually changed it to that a few minutes ago just forgot to update my question. It still says I have null values even though my database is filled with info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not initialized `CommonViewModel` properly. Following code snippent may help you.

```
 public class HomeController
 {
    private DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new CommonViewModel();
        viewModel.users = db.User.ToList();
        viewModel.courses = db.Course.ToList();

        return View(viewModel);
    }        
}
```

See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aqkE8v) dotnetfiddle. Hope this will help you.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/aqkE8v

Comment: I already have a database full of information I dont need to add information.

Comment: Yes i know, you should your data instead of mine. Take a look to the link given.

Comment: Its still highlighting `Model.users' and saying `object reference not set to an instance of an object` 

How is this model pulling the data from the db? I don't see it in the controller code

Comment: I added your controller code exactly and now I'm not getting any errors but the page is blank.

Comment: As you updated your question it always be blank because your `List` are empty.

Comment: So how can I populate them with the data from my database?

Comment: I don't see any changes.

Comment: go through carefully.

Comment: You're populating your lists manually. I already have data in the database. I need to query the database and save it in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Either your model should contain the definition of Users; it's contain property named user.

```
public class CommonViewModel
{
    public List<User> Users {get ; set; }
    public List<Course> courses {get ; set; }
}
```

or, you should return the List from Action. In that case you should be changing as

```
@model List<TEST.Models.CommonViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.UserPassword)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: User is highlighted with errors saying the model doesn't contain a definition for it and if I change it to users it says `List<User> does not contain a definition for UserID`

Comment: `Foreach` is done on Model.Users in your question. So item will have the required properties to display

Comment: `users` != `Users`. Make sure that you got the casing right, since it's bouncing around between your question and the answer here. FWIW, style guidelines state that properties should be title-cased: `Users`, not `users`.